# How to find source IP Address?

Tags: networking, socket

How to find the default Default IP Address if my I am connected to more than one network? I found one link

> http://libtins.github.io/tutorial/sending/

But In "Sending network layer PDUs" It is written that

```
PacketSender sender;
```

IP pkt = IP("192.168.0.1") / TCP(22) / RawPDU("foo");
sender.send(pkt);

Note that no source address was specified in the IP constructor. This uses by default the address 0.0.0.0. However, when sending network layer PDUs, if the source address is 0.0.0.0, the PDU will perform a lookup on the routing table to find out which should be the source address and automatically sets it.

So, Is there any way to find the source address using c++?

Answer (score 1):

Once you connect the socket, you can call `getsockname` on it to find out the local IP address.